# Where is Facebook API's get_loggedin_user function

Tags: php, facebook

I am using face book API and i have this below code:

```
include("../src/facebook.php");
// start facebook api with the codes defined in step 1.
//$fb=new Facebook(FB_API_KEY,FB_SECRET);
//$fb_user=$fb->get_loggedin_user();

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_API_KEY,
  'secret' => FB_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true, 
));

$fb_user=$facebook->get_loggedin_user();
```

BUT..
This function **get_loggedin_user()** is not available in facebook.php class

Please give me some details about this function. How I can use it.

Regards

Comment: You should really accept some answers. Other users aren't going to be so open with their answers if they're not going to get reputation rewards man. 11% - jesus

Comment: Go back and look at your questions you've asked http://stackoverflow.com/users/188856/deepak and which ever answer was the most helpful/solution to your question click the green tick.

Comment: Ok Daniel, I'll care in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function is available in api file
i dont remember name but file name contains "api" in it
under this folder
../src/

Comment: Yes the path is /src/facebook.php. But above function is not declared in facebook class which provided by face book sdk.

Comment: in that folder, is there any file with api in its name? that file contain this function

Comment: oh i just checked i think api has changed now, so i am not sure about file, but why you want to see that function, you can call that function with facebook object directly